# htaccess mod-rewrite file name, how to format the regex

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a directory in my root called images. I have a naming convention of number-category.jpg. I am using this convention through a PHP script and would like to have a RewriteRule in my htaccess that does something to the effect of word-word-category-number.jpg for SEO purposes.

So what was once '`10-abstract.jpg`' is now '`fine-art-abstract-art-10.jpg`'

I was reading some tutorials and came up with below with no success:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]-[a-z])-art.jpg$ /2/art/$1-$2.jpg [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `word-word-category-number.jpg`, try:

```
RewriteRule ^[^-]+-[^-]+-([^-]+)-([0-9]+)\.jpg$ /2/art/$2-$1.jpg [L]
```

But that's not going to work for your example because `fine-art-abstract-art-10.jpg` is `word-word-category-word-number.jpg`. You can add another section for that:

```
RewriteRule ^[^-]+-[^-]+-([^-]+)-[^-]+-([0-9]+)\.jpg$ /2/art/$2-$1.jpg [L]
```

And that'll take a request for `http://your.domain.com/fine-art-abstract-art-10.jpg` and serve `/2/art/10-abstract.jpg`.